# How to compute the following double integral?

Tags: calculus, integration

I would like to solve the following:

$$ \int_0^1 \int_0^2 \sqrt{1+4x^2+4y^2} \,dy \, dx$$

I tried to use trig substitutions by letting:
$$y= \sqrt {\frac{1+4x^2}{4}} \cdot \tan(\theta)$$
$$ \partial y = \sqrt {\frac{1+4x^2}{4}} \cdot \sec^2{(\theta)} \partial \, \theta $$

Which ended up giving me:

$$ \int_0^1 \int_0^2 \frac{1+4x^2}{2} \cdot \sec^3(\theta) \, d\theta \, dx$$

But things got ugly pretty soon as I integrated $\sec^3(\theta)$.

---

Wolfram aplha gives a numerical approximate solution of: 
[Wolfram Alpha Solution](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integration%20%5B%2F%2Fmath%3Asqrt(%201%2B%204x%5E2%20%2B4y%5E2)%2F%2F%5D%20%5B%2F%2Fmath%3Ady%20dx%2F%2F%5D%20for%20x%20from%20%5B%2F%2Fmath%3A0%2F%2F%5D%20to%20%5B%2F%2Fmath%3A1%2F%2F%5D%20for%20y%20from%20%5B%2F%2Fmath%3A0%2F%2F%5D%20to%20%5B%2F%2Fmath%3A2%2F%2F%5D)

Can this only be done by numerical methods?

Thanks,

-Sigma

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_secant_cubed

Comment: The integral of secant cubed is definitely possible. Try integration by parts a few times, and you should get a negative "repeat" of the integral of secant cubed on the "right hand side," from where you can add this to the "left hand side," divide by 2, and get your result.

Comment: You shouldn't have $\theta$ going from $0$ to $2$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I thought of the following but I am not convinced it's a good way to proceed: $$\int_0^1 \int_0^2 \sqrt{1+4x^2+4y^2} \,dy \, dx $$
$$=\int_0^{\arctan 2} \int_0^{\sec\theta} \sqrt{1+4r^2\,{}} \, (r \, dr \, d\theta) + \int_{\arctan 2}^{\pi/2} \int_0^{2\csc\theta} \sqrt{1+4r^2\,{}} \, (r \, dr \, d\theta)$$ ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: How did you come up with the integration bounds?

Comment: @CivilSigma : You have a rectangle.  Draw the picture.  The ray from the origin outward starts out horizontal, so $\theta=0$, and increases until it hits the upper right corner of the rectangle, and during that sweep it intersects the right side of the rectangle rather than the top of the rectangle.  Then it goes from there up to a vertical position, and then it intersects the top rather than the right side.  The reason $r$ goes from $0$ to $\sec\theta$ in the first integral is that secant is hypotenuse over adjacent, and the adjacent side is $1$, and $r$ should go up to the length of.....

Comment: ....the hypotenuse.  In the second integral, the opposite side is $2$, and cosecant is hypotenuse over opposite. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider first $$A=\int \sqrt{1+4x^2+4y^2} \,dy $$ and make a change of variable such that $$y=\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{4 x^2+1} \sinh (z)$$ which gives $$dy=\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{4 x^2+1} \cosh (z)\, dz$$ So, $$A=\frac{1}{2} \left(4 x^2+1\right) \int\cosh ^2(z)\, dz=\frac{1}{4} \left(4 x^2+1\right) \int \big(1+\cosh(2z)\big)\,dz$$ $$A=\frac{1}{4} \left(4 x^2+1\right)\Big(z+\frac 12 \sinh(2z)\Big)$$ Back to $y$, this then gives $$A=\frac{1}{2} y \sqrt{4 x^2+4 y^2+1}+\frac{1}{4} \left(4 x^2+1\right) \log
   \left(\sqrt{4 x^2+4 y^2+1}+2 y\right)$$ So, for $$B=\int_0^2 \sqrt{1+4x^2+4y^2} \,dy$$ $$B=\sqrt{4 x^2+17}-\frac{1}{8} \left(4 x^2+1\right) \log \left(4
   x^2+1\right)+\left(x^2+\frac{1}{4}\right) \log \left(\sqrt{4 x^2+17}+4\right) $$ So, what is left to be computed is now $$C=\int_0^1 B\, dx$$ which is not the most pleasant task to do.

I must confess that, at this point, I felt stuck and almost ready to give up. However, integrating each piece and using integration by parts to get rid of the logarithms $$C_1=\int \sqrt{4 x^2+17}\, dx=\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{4 x^2+17} x+\frac{17}{4} \sinh ^{-1}\left(\frac{2
   x}{\sqrt{17}}\right)$$ $$C_2=\int \left(4 x^2+1\right) \log \left(4
   x^2+1\right)\,dx$$ $$C_2=-\frac{8 x^3}{9}+x \log \left(4 x^2+1\right)+\frac{4}{3} x^3 \log \left(4
   x^2+1\right)-\frac{4 x}{3}+\frac{2}{3} \tan ^{-1}(2 x)$$ $$C_3=\int \left(x^2+\frac{1}{4}\right) \log \left(\sqrt{4 x^2+17}+4\right)\,dx $$ $$C_3=-\frac{x^3}{9}+\frac{1}{6} \sqrt{4 x^2+17} x+\frac{1}{4} x \log \left(\sqrt{4
   x^2+17}+4\right)-\frac{1}{12} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{8 x}{\sqrt{4
   x^2+17}}\right)+\frac{1}{3} x^3 \log \left(\sqrt{4
   x^2+17}+4\right)-\frac{x}{6}+\frac{1}{12} \tan ^{-1}(2 x)-\frac{13}{12} \sinh
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{2 x}{\sqrt{17}}\right)$$ Combining all pieces and using the given bounds for $x$, I arrived to a nasty expression which gives for the posted integral $$\frac{1}{24} \left(16 \sqrt{21}-7 \log (5)+14 \log \left(4+\sqrt{21}\right)-2 \tan
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{8}{\sqrt{21}}\right)+76 \sinh
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{17}}\right)\right)$$ which is $\approx 5.2335207996970570623$ as given by Wolfram Alpha.

I sincerely hope and wish that a simpler solution will be given to this problem.

Comment: I tried to solve using the normal trig functions. It turns out to be way more nastier ;(. Thank you very much for this.

Comment: You are very welcome ! But, this has been a nightmare ! Cheers :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can try the substitutions $x = \frac12 \tan(\theta)\sin(\phi), y = \frac12 \tan(\theta)\cos(\phi)$.